# Traveling close to the speed of light, would a person (or anything else) have a longer existence or would the existence be passing in slow motion?

Tags: special-relativity, time, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

If something, let's say, an electron or a person, travels at some speed close to the speed of light, time would slow down, right?

But would it be passing in slow motion or would it have a bigger amount of time to 'live'?

Comment: *"time would slow down, right?"*  - according to whom?  Certainly not the person since, for them, it's all the other stuff that is moving while they're at rest.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to you, i.e, in your reference frame, you would be the same. You would not see length contraction or experience time dilation. However,say, from the frame of the earth, the people would see you at slow-mo.

Answer (score -3):

From your perspective, time will be passing the same rate. But when you stop, you will find that a lot of time passed, so there is no slow motion from your perspective.
And, STOP MARKING THIS AS A DUPLICATE FOR GOD SAKE FOR THE OTHERS

Comment: I didn't do anything on purpouse. So there's no need of being rude. Thank you for answering my question, anyway.

Comment: Other users will just flag it as a duplicate and leave it unanswered. It happens to me many times and its upsetting

Comment: Possibly because it actually is a duplicate. Oftentimes a link to the duplicate question, already answered, is also provided.

Comment: Every question deserves an answer as long it is valid.

Comment: Why should the same question be answered repeatedly on a website? It's redundant and makes no sense.